# Vidyo.io Camera and Mic not working on chrome

Tags: vidyo

Chrome Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)

The vidyo.io demo application is defaulting to the video-placeholder image on Chrome. As shown on the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZwjp.png)

The camera is enabled. The Demo (https://developer.vidyo.io/#/demo) is working for Microsoft Edge and Mozilla also. We are experiencing this issue just in Chrome.
The strange thing is that sometimes it's working. Without any setup change.

The vidyo sample (downloaded from here: https://developer.vidyo.io/#/documentation), which is included in the VidyoClient WebSDK has the same issue - it is redirecting me to the default svg, however in comparison to the Vidyo demo it never worked even occasionally.

Do you have any clue, what the issue could be?
Thanks

Comment: Can you test here to see if it is working?
https://static.vidyo.io/latest/connector/VidyoConnector.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows you can host it on IIS port 80 and run the application on the default IIS web server() on the localhost. Due to chrome's security restrictions for enabling the camera and microphone, running on the web server (either python or IIS) is needed.

For example : http://localhost/VidyoClient-WebSDK/VidyoClient-WebSDK/samples/VidyoConnector/js/VidyoConnector.html